# Tensorflow variables' name changed after function calling

Tags: tensorflow, static-variables, variable-names

I am trying to write my own batch normalization codes. Therefore, I test the codes below. In order to track the online average mean and variance, I pass them as parameters into the getsta() function. However, I find that the names of "avg_mean" and "avg_variance" changed. Although I could manually force change their names later, it seems Tensorflow treat every name as a separate variable.

```
def getsta(x,avg_mean,avg_variance):
  print('getsta start...')

  decay=0.9

  mean = tf.get_variable(
          'mean', [1], tf.float32,
          initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0, tf.float32))
  variance = tf.get_variable(
          'howvariance', [1], tf.float32,
          initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1.0, tf.float32))
  '''
  if (avg_mean == 0.0): 
      avg_mean = tf.get_variable(
              'avg_mean', [1], tf.float32,
              initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0, tf.float32))
  if (avg_variance == 0.0):
      avg_variance = tf.get_variable(
              'avg_variance', [1], tf.float32,
              initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0, tf.float32))
  '''
  mean, variance = tf.nn.moments(x, [0], name='moments')

  avg_mean -= (1.0 - decay) * (avg_mean - mean)
  avg_variance -= (1.0 - decay) * (avg_variance - variance)

  return x, mean, variance, avg_mean, avg_variance

def train():
  x1 = tf.constant([1,2,3,4], tf.float32)
  x2 = tf.constant([5,6,7,8], tf.float32)
  x3 = tf.constant([1,3,5,7], tf.float32)
  x4 = tf.constant([4,8,12,16], tf.float32)

  with tf.variable_scope("AAA") as scopeA:
    avg_mean1 = tf.get_variable(
              'test1', [1], tf.float32,
              initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0, tf.float32))
    avg_variance1 = tf.get_variable(
              'test2', [1], tf.float32,
              initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0, tf.float32))
    print([avg_mean1.name, avg_variance1.name])
    y1, mean1, variance1, avg_mean1, avg_variance1 = getsta(x1,avg_mean1,avg_variance1)
    print([avg_mean1.name, avg_variance1.name])
    scopeA.reuse_variables()
    print([avg_mean1.name, avg_variance1.name])
    y1, mean1, variance1, avg_mean1, avg_variance1 = getsta(x2,avg_mean1,avg_variance1)
    print([avg_mean1.name, avg_variance1.name])
    avg_mean1 = tf.identity(avg_mean1, name='avg_mean')
    avg_variance1 = tf.identity(avg_variance1, name='avg_variance')
    print([avg_mean1.name, avg_variance1.name])

  with tf.variable_scope("BBB") as scopeB:
    avg_mean2 = tf.get_variable(
              'test1', [1], tf.float32,
              initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0, tf.float32))
    avg_variance2 = tf.get_variable(
              'test2', [1], tf.float32,
              initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0, tf.float32))
    print([avg_mean2.name, avg_variance2.name])
    y2, mean2, variance2, avg_mean2, avg_variance2 = getsta(x3, avg_mean2, avg_variance2)
    print([avg_mean2.name, avg_variance2.name])
    scopeB.reuse_variables()
    print([avg_mean2.name, avg_variance2.name])
    y2, mean2, variance2, avg_mean2, avg_variance2 = getsta(x4, avg_mean2, avg_variance2)
    print([avg_mean2.name, avg_variance2.name])
    avg_mean2 = tf.identity(avg_mean2, name='avg_mean')
    avg_variance2 = tf.identity(avg_variance2, name='avg_variance')
    print([avg_mean2.name, avg_variance2.name])

  saver = tf.train.Saver()
  sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  print(sess.run([y1, mean1, variance1, avg_mean1, avg_variance1]))
  print(sess.run([y2, mean2, variance2, avg_mean2, avg_variance2]))

  allVars = tf.global_variables()
  values = sess.run(allVars)
  for var, val in zip(allVars, values):
    print(var.name, val)

  saver.save(sess, "/tmp/test_EMA/var_save.ckpt")
```

After running the above train() function, I got output as

```
['AAA/test1:0', 'AAA/test2:0']
getsta start...
['AAA/sub_1:0', 'AAA/sub_3:0']
['AAA/sub_1:0', 'AAA/sub_3:0']
getsta start...
['AAA/sub_5:0', 'AAA/sub_7:0']
['AAA/avg_mean:0', 'AAA/avg_variance:0']
['BBB/test1:0', 'BBB/test2:0']
getsta start...
['BBB/sub_1:0', 'BBB/sub_3:0']
['BBB/sub_1:0', 'BBB/sub_3:0']
getsta start...
['BBB/sub_5:0', 'BBB/sub_7:0']
['BBB/avg_mean:0', 'BBB/avg_variance:0']
[array([ 5.,  6.,  7.,  8.], dtype=float32), 6.5, 1.25, array([ 0.875], dtype=float32), array([ 0.23750001], dtype=float32)]
[array([  4.,   8.,  12.,  16.], dtype=float32), 10.0, 20.0, array([ 1.36000001], dtype=float32), array([ 2.45000005], dtype=float32)]
AAA/test1:0 [ 0.]
AAA/test2:0 [ 0.]
AAA/mean:0 [ 0.]
AAA/howvariance:0 [ 1.]
BBB/test1:0 [ 0.]
BBB/test2:0 [ 0.]
BBB/mean:0 [ 0.]
BBB/howvariance:0 [ 1.]
```

I have several questions:

1. Is there any way to record the "avg_mean" without changing its name? I want to load the final updated values when loading the model.
2. Is it possible to define "avg_mean" inside the getsta() function, while still keeping it like a static variable, i.e., its initial value is from the last time's calling but not always starting from 0.
3. When I print out all variables, why the names and values both seem not correct as the last eight rows in the output? I expect the output is

   ```
   AAA/avg_mean:0 [0.875]
   AAA/avg_variance:0 [0.23750001]
   BBB/avg_mean:0 [1.36000001]
   BBB/avg_variance:0 [2.45000005]
   ```

Thank you for your help in advance!

--------------------Update--------------------

I revised my codes as below

```
def train():
  x1 = tf.constant([1,2,3,4], tf.float32)
  x2 = tf.constant([5,6,7,8], tf.float32)
  x3 = tf.constant([1,3,5,7], tf.float32)
  x4 = tf.constant([4,8,12,16], tf.float32)

  with tf.variable_scope("AAA") as scopeA:
    avg_mean1 = tf.get_variable(
              'avg_mean', [1], tf.float32,
              initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0, tf.float32))
    avg_variance1 = tf.get_variable(
              'avg_variance', [1], tf.float32,
              initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0, tf.float32))
    y1, mean1, variance1 = getsta(x1,avg_mean1,avg_variance1)
    scopeA.reuse_variables()
    y1, mean1, variance1 = getsta(x2,avg_mean1,avg_variance1)
    print([avg_mean1.name, avg_variance1.name])

  with tf.variable_scope("BBB") as scopeB:
    avg_mean2 = tf.get_variable(
              'avg_mean', [1], tf.float32,
              initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0, tf.float32))
    avg_variance2 = tf.get_variable(
              'avg_variance', [1], tf.float32,
              initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0, tf.float32))
    y2, mean2, variance2 = getsta(x3, avg_mean2, avg_variance2)
    scopeB.reuse_variables()
    y2, mean2, variance2 = getsta(x4, avg_mean2, avg_variance2)
    print([avg_mean2.name, avg_variance2.name])

  saver = tf.train.Saver()
  sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  print(sess.run([y1, mean1, variance1, avg_mean1, avg_variance1]))
  print(sess.run([y2, mean2, variance2, avg_mean2, avg_variance2]))

  allVars = tf.global_variables()
  values = sess.run(allVars)
  for var, val in zip(allVars, values):
    print(var.name, val)

  saver.save(sess, "/tmp/test_EMA/var_save.ckpt")
```

Now the variables' names are fixed. However, the outputs (variables' values) seem incorrect. The outputs are

```
[array([ 5.,  6.,  7.,  8.], dtype=float32), 6.5, 1.25, array([ 0.], dtype=float32), array([ 0.], dtype=float32)]
[array([  4.,   8.,  12.,  16.], dtype=float32), 10.0, 20.0, array([ 0.], dtype=float32), array([ 0.], dtype=float32)]
AAA/avg_mean:0 [ 0.]
AAA/avg_variance:0 [ 0.]
AAA/mean:0 [ 0.]
AAA/variance:0 [ 1.]
BBB/avg_mean:0 [ 0.]
BBB/avg_variance:0 [ 0.]
BBB/mean:0 [ 0.]
```

How should I modify my codes to get the correct results? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the problems in your code that needs to be fixed:

1- At the following line you are replacing `avg_variance1` with an `operation` returned by `getsta`. You must not do that. When you have created the variable `avg_variance1` and pass it to `getsta`the variable will be updated everywhere in the computation graph and TensorFlow will take care of that, you don't need to explicitly do that. As long as you are referring to a `variable` by its `name` you are fine. TensorFlow variables are not like regular Python variables.

```
y1, mean1, variance1, avg_mean1, avg_variance1 = getsta(x1,avg_mean1,avg_variance1)
```

(you need to fix this for avg_mean1, avg_mean2, etc)

2- `avg_mean2`, `avg_variance2`, `avg_mean2`, and `avg_variance2` are `Tensor` and not `variable`. So they are not in the list of `variables` you are printing out.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. I now know the reason of the name change and can fix it. However, I find that the results are not correct; it seems that the variables are always re-set to zero. My revised codes are as modified in the original post. @Ali, Would you please help to have a look? Thank you.